# Is there any way that this Java code can be improved?

Tags: java, performance, function, finance

Can someone help me to optimize this code?

```
public final List<Double> Imprve() {    
List<Double> locDbValueList = new LinkedList<Double> ();
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; ++i) {
     Calendar locMyCalendar = new GregorianCalendar ();
      locDbValueList.add(getNewDbValue(locMyCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), i));
}
    updateList(locDbValueList) ;    
    Integer locResult = 0 ;
    for (int i = 0; i < locDbValueList.size(); ++i) {
      final Integer locTempVal = doOperation(locDbValueList.get(i));
      if (locTempVal != null) {
        locResult += locTempVal;
      }
    }
    applyResult(locResult) ;
    return locDbValueList;
}

private Double getNewDbValue(int parYear, int parIdx) { … }
private void updateList(List<Double> valList) { … }   //Modifies value not size
private int doOperation (Double parDbRefValue) { … }
private void applyResult (int parIntValue) { … }*
```

I want to modify class Imprve to improve timeliness of the function.

Comment: Have you tried profiling the code?

Comment: If you want to optimise this code, get a profiler and do it yourself. If you want a code review, try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How can we make an advice if you haven't describe external functions? Say, what getNewDbValue() does? Does it access a database? It's very inefficient to retreive one value at a time. Retrieve them all at once (50000 is not that much).

Comment: @JavaBlood: what is up with the edit vandalism attempt?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10664366/2961  Not cool.

Answer (score 2):

I am not putting the performence of your code on test. But, I do see following issue in the code given.

1. By the Java Coding Convention, every method name should start with a small letter. So you should rename your method `Imprve` to `improve`.
2. You have created `locMyCalendar` a `Calendar` instance in the for loop. From this instance your are reading only `Year` property. It is completely unnecessary. You should remove this line from this place. and put is somewhere up. This is a performance hit also.
3. The null check for the `locTempVal` is not required. As, `doOperation` method returns `int` and the `int` is not very likely to be a `null` value.
4. And use "int" instead of "Integer" for the type of locResult and locTempVal because creating Integer objects each time is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Use an ArrayList instead of LinkedList.

As a rule of a thumb, a vector (like Java's ArrayList) container will outperform a linked list one (like LinkedList).  This will always be true in terms of memory size, because the vector container doesn't impose a per element overhead for housekeeping data.  In most cases time performance will also be better, due to better locality of reference and smaller memory size (therefore requiring fewer expensive memory accesses).  A linked list container may outperform a vector container in terms of speed, only when you have many additions and removals of elements within the data.  Note that the locality of reference improvements may not be as pronounced in Java as they are e.g. in C++ when the container stores objects, because these are anyway accessed through a pointer indirection.

In your case all decision criteria point toward using a vector container (ArrayList). You know the container's size in advance, you don't add elements in the container's middle, and you store Double values, which the compiler may store as plain double in the container.

Comment: Thankz dis seems reasonable... and appreciated ur explanation Sir, Just one small question can arraylist be used by calling functions for paths?

Comment: Only change LinkedList to ArrayList. Leave the other List references as they were.

Comment: Pardon but using ArrayList instead of LinkedList when it is full of auto-boxing and 50000 useless Calendars is like seeing only one tree in a forest